# Namespace & Class Conflict

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, conflict

I'm facing a problem with a conflict between the DateTime class and a namespace for some unknown reason was also called DateTime.

Assembly **CompanyDateTime** has namespace **Company.DateTime**

My Application is in the namespace: **Company**

the problem is that everytime I need to use **DateTime** class, I have to explicitely say **System.DateTime** is their any way of getting around this?

Is is possible to say **SomeRandomStuff = Company.DateTime** and have **DateTime** always be **System.DateTime**

Note:

1. I need to reference this Assembly in my application eventhough I do not use it because some Assembly that I need actually uses this class.
2. I can use an entry on the app.config file to identify a dependent assembly but I cannot do that since company policy is against it and all referenced assembly needs to be in the output folder.
3. Deployment goes through a build server

Possible Resolution?
Is is possible for **CompanyDateTime** to get automatically deployed to the output folder without adding it in the reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Question :** the problem is that everytime I need to use DateTime class, I have to explicitely say System.DateTime is their any way of getting around this

Answer : Already answered above - use an Alias eg

`using CompanyDateTime = Company.DateTime;`

`using StandardDateTime = System.DateTime;`

**Question :** Is is possible for CompanyDateTime to get automatically deployed to the output folder without adding it in the reference?

Answer : Put this dll in the application root folder and create a postbuild event that copies this to the output folder. You can use the regular DOS COPY command here.

[Refer link for postbuild event details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I used your postbuild command to copy the file over.  It worked and I'm hoping that It still works on the build server.  Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Yes, use a using directive at the top of your code files that reference it like this.

```
using SomeRandomStuff = Company.DateTime;
```

**Edit**:  you may also need another one to resolve the ambiguity:

```
using DateTime = System.DateTime;
```

Comment: It does not work, I still need to say System.DateTime to use the DateTime class.

Answer (score 4):

Give the assembly an alias (the default is `global`, set yours to something else). You can set this in Visual Studio's property window when you select a reference, or using a compile switch if you're manually compiling. The compiler will only resolve things in the global alias, unless you specify an external alias at the top of your code file (`extern alias myalias`).

Note, this is different from the namespace alias others have mentioned. With this you should simply be able to use `DateTime` to refer to the System.DateTime, rather than using another name. If you need to refer to the other one later, you'd need to specify `myalias::Company.DateTime...`

Comment: Yes It did work for me and compiled properly but I lost the Intellsence for the variable.  Thats the only reason I did not use it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [**alias**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(v=VS.100).aspx).

If you want to use System.DateTime without having to use System, then try:

`using SysDate = System.DateTime;`

Then, just reference it like you would a class:

`SysDate mySystemDotDateTime = new SysDate();`

Comment: I used the postbuild command rather than using an alias.  It would have worked but I found the other solution better.  Thank you.